# Let's suppose there is only one object in this universe. May that be a quark, an atom, etc. What will be the consequences?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, forces, universe, thought-experiment

*I'm not a physics expert, but this question really intrigued me, so I thought "why not ask those who are"!*

> Let's suppose there is only one object in this universe. May that be a quark, an atom, etc. What will be the consequences?

In terms relating to, *Gravitational force, Electrical force, etc.* individually, and in terms of *Grand Unified Theory.*

And also in terms of *Quantum Mechanics.* I'm assuming there will be no *Quantum Mechanics*, but correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: I would normally want to see more evidence of prior thought by the questioner before deciding to answer. But a brief answer is that it does not make sense to speak of even a single supposedly simple entity without a huge amount of maths and physics to say what it is you are referring to.

Comment: Some descriptions of accelerated cosmic expansion suggest that, in the far future, expansion will carry distant galaxies beyond the visible horizon, and our visible universe will contain only the galaxies in our Local Group. A similar argument for an observer in the intergalactic void might predict a (very!) distant future where one or fewer atoms are present within a cosmic horizon. I think it's fair to ask what such a universe would look like, but I'm not sure that the "dark energy" field which drives our accelerating expansion would be the same in such a universe as it is today.

Comment: @AndrewStean _Suppose, cosmos is build of only non-baryonic matter, and we've to start from scratch to build the fundamentals, no cosmological constant, no big bang only quantum vacuum, then how can we go about that?_ Before, I put a single particle to accommodate gravity in _"theory of everything"_, but then gandalf6 reminded me of virtual particles, which I've known by different terms, _Annihilation_ or _Hawking radiation_. So now I've these short lived matter where I can fill the gap for gravity. Which again leads me to another question, _Do virtual particles follow quantum entanglement?_

Comment: @AndrewSteane and _everyone_, I'm a _developer_ by profession, please don't be mad at me! I can understand if I'm not invited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An atom and a quark are very different objects. A quark is a fundamental particle, whereas an atom is a made up of many fundamental particles (quarks and electrons) which are continually exchanging other fundamental particles such as photons and gluons.

To keep things simple, let's suppose your hypothetical universe just contains one quark. As far as we know, quantum physics will still apply in your one-particle universe, and in particular the uncertainty principle will apply. This means that your single fundamental particle will be surrounded by a sea of virtual particles, and the more precisely you try to describe it, the more complicated it will appear. In simple terms, quantum physics tells us that the model of a single, isolated particle is only a very rough approximation to reality.

Comment: _"the more precisely you try to describe it, the more complicated it will appear."_
can you give me reference to _readings_ or _topic name_ or suggest me a _book_, technicalities like equations, mathematics and derivations will not be a problem but abundant theory to explain it? i want to build an understanding around it.

Comment: [Quantum theory](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319095608?utm_campaign=bookpage_about_buyonpublisherssite&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=springerlink) I'll try to read this book, it contains something like you mentioned, _Quantum mechanics of single particle_, will see. thanks. :)

Comment: If you are starting from scratch but aren't put off by some mathematics then "Quantum Mechanics: The Theoretical Minimum" by Leonard Susskind and Art Friedman is a good place to start. The book came from a lecture series delivered by Susskind, which is now available on-line at http://theoreticalminimum.com/courses/quantum-mechanics/2012/winter.

Answer (score 0):

With Quantum Mechanics (actually quantum field theory) there is no single elementary particle, but "the electron field", the "quark field" etc and their excitations (little waves in the field that we call elementary particles). OK, you can remove the "quantum fluctuations" (namely the broth of particles generated by the quantum field) and think about a theory where there is gravity (classical General Relativity) and a single classical field (e.g. the quark field or the electron field, or the photon field...). This is already a complex system which dynamics is governed by non-trivial equations. On the other hand, maybe you are asking about a single point particle (that you call "quark" or "atom") that is not the by-product of a field (i.e. it's existence is not related to the fact that it is an elementary wave propagating in a more fundamental entity called "field"). In this case my feeling is that the situation is more boring and nothing happens: the particle (supposed space exist or makes sense when there is a single point object) moves with  uniform linear motion forever.

Comment: okay, i anticipated the boredom. But I've three more questions, _1. can we use this as "base case" when working or "proving" the unified field equation?_  _2. Will the quantum fields still be there?_ and _3. what hold the object in-place in vacuum, suppose if it's not moving?_